# When starting Backbone.history, TypeError is thrown

Tags: backbone.js, router

I have a very basic router to get things going, but I cant load Backbone.history.start() to start handling routes. jquery, underscore & backbone are loaded. Here's my basic router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "*query": "defaultRoute"
    },

        initialize: function() {
            Backbone.history.start();
        },

        defaultRoute: function(query) {
            console.log(query);
        }
    });

var app_router = new AppRouter;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

located in my backbone library file. Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you have posted above seems to be issue free. [Check it out in  this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUYX9/) to see.


I am still not sure exactly where you issue is coming from, but the error is indicating you are attempting to use the on method (coming from Backbone.Events) on an object that does not have it.

If you post some more context/code maybe I can give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, can you move the `Backbone.history.start();` code outside the Router creation? Basically put it after you fully bootstrap your application, like this:

```
$(function(){
  new AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: Mmmm... it does not seem something Backbone related then. Can you get a bit more debugging info? Like in the Chrome or Firebug console it will tellyou what line and what file you get the error and you can stick a breakpoint there and see the call stack

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but the problem is likely in the 'events' property of the current view, which should contain an object with interface event mappings: http://backbonejs.org/#View.